# Getting native linking error while building the iOS app with static library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to bind the third party static library with iOS app using binding project. After adding the static library binding project builds successfully. But my iOS app showing some native linking errors as shown in the attached image. Could anyone help me on this please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The EA* errors can be resolved by adding this to the LinkWith attribute of the static library in your binding project:

```
[assembly: LinkWith (..., Frameworks = "ExternalAccessory")]
```

The SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress error can be resolved by adding `SystemConfiguration` to the list of frameworks in the LinkWith attribute (like above).

The BZ2_bzBuffToBuffCompress error is probably a function your static library references, but doesn't include. You *might* be able to work around it by adding -dead_strip to linker flags:

```
[assembly: LinkWith (..., LinkerFlags = "-dead_strip")]
```

which will tell the native linker to remove unused code, which may remove the code that calls BZ2_bzBuffToBuffCompress, thus working around it. It may also remove too much code, so you'll have to try and see what happens.

Comment: Hi Rolf, Thanks for your comment. I made the changes as per your comments. But still facing some other native inking errors 

http://i.stack.imgur.com/DrUk0.png

Comment: Try setting `IsCxx = true` in the LinkWith attribute.

Comment: Great!! it reduced my build error count from 103 to 22. Could u please check this http://i.stack.imgur.com/nT8ER.png screenshot. Please help me to fix this errors.

Comment: Did you add `SystemConfiguration` to the list of frameworks? That's where those functions are: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already added System configuration in my frameworks. But still facing the native linking error like "MT5210", "MT5201" and "MT5202".

Comment: Try adding `Security` too. It's simple really: just google for the symbol the error message is complaining about, and you'll easily find out which framework you need to link with.